# Django pass var from view to two template in the same time

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-views

I would like to pass var from a view to the template and to a javascript library (javascript.js) in the same time. Is it possible?

view.py:

```
def setAppOptions(request, map_name):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        app_selected = EzApp.objects.get(app_name=app_name, created_by=request.user)
        formset = ezAppOptionFormSet(user=request.user, instance=app_selected)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            formset = ezAppOptionFormSet(request.POST, instance=app_selected, user=request.user)
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()

        return render_to_response("manage_app_options.html", {'formset': formset}, context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 
    else:
        error_msg = u"You are not logged in"
        return HttpResponseServerError(error_msg)
```

template:

```
{% extends "basemap.html" %}
{% block library %}
#I want to pass var to this library and to this template in the same time...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascript.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>
    <h1>Define App options</h1>
    {% if formset.errors %}
        <p style="color: red;">
            Please correct the error{{ formset.errors|pluralize }} below.
        </p>
    {% endif %}
    <form method="post" action="" encrypt="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ formset.as_p }} 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="initialize()">
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'pass it to your javascript library'? If the variable is in your html surely it's available to your javascript.js file? Why don't you tell us what your variable is, and what you want to do with it (both in the html and the javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you want to keep your javascript files js only, one way to achieve this is to have your js `initialize` accept some config data. in your html template (which is rendered by django and thus has access to your context vars you pass data in

javascript.js

```
...
function initialize(options) {
...
```

template.html

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="initialize({
    myvar: {{ value_from_django }},
    other_stuff: 10
})">
```

Comment: This solution works, but do I have to assume that its impossible to use django tags in the template and the javascript.js from a single view?

Comment: Unless you include your javascript.js file directly in the template. {% include "static/javascript.js %}. That'd let you maintain separate files.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "pass" the variable to the library.

Just set it in a script tag like so:

```
{% block library %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var foo = "{{ variable }}";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascript.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

You can then reference it within your JS as either `VARIABLE` or `window.foo`.